# What is a pivotal statistic?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, estimation, inference

I'm currently reading *"Computer Age Statistical Inference"* by Efron and Hastie.

In section 2.1, they talk about some of the mechanisms that frequentist inference uses to circumvent the defect of having to calculate properties of estimators $\hat{\Theta} = t(\mathbf{X})$ of an unknown distribution $F$.

One of these mechanisms, they say, is the use of *pivotal statistics*, which they define as not depending upon the underlying probability of $F$. They give an example of a two-sample $t$ statistic as one that does not depend on the underlying distribution.

More specifically, they say that:

1. given two normally distributed i.i.d. samples $\mathbf{x_1} = (x_{1,1}, \ldots x_{1,n})$ and $\mathbf{x_2} = (x_{2,1}, \ldots x_{2,n})$.
2. given the null hypothesis $H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2$
3. a test statistic $\hat{\theta} = \bar{\mathbf{x_2}} - \bar{\mathbf{x_1}}$ would have distribution $\sim N\Big(0,\sigma^2(\frac{1}{n_1} + \frac{1}{n_2})\Big)$ under the null hypothesis. In this case $\sigma$ would be **non-pivotal**
4. Then he proposes that the way we do $t = \frac{\bar{\mathbf{x_2}} - \bar{\mathbf{x_1}}}{\hat{\sigma}(\frac{1}{n_1} + \frac{1}{n_2})^{1/2}}$, is **pivotal**.

I really didn't understand the difference between these two, and thus, as I didn't really understand how $t$ doesn't rely on the sample.

Comment: The value of $t$ certainly relies on the sample. The distribution of $t$ doesn't depend on the value of $\sigma$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *population* standard deviation  $\sigma$ depends on the (unknown) **distribution**, $E$. The *sample* standard deviation $\hat{\sigma}$ depends only on the (known) **data**, $\boldsymbol{x}$.

Because it is a [consistent estimator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_estimator), $\hat{\sigma}\to\sigma$ as sample size goes to infinity. But with a finite sample, only $\hat{\sigma}$ is knowable.

Comment: As a comment, what really opened my eyes in addition to your comment, was the actual derivation of the t statistic, which can be found here: http://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1014&context=gradreports.

Comment: whether $\hat \sigma$ is pivotal or not in this case should be if $\hat \sigma$ depends on $\theta$ (the target quantity of the test) or not right?

Comment: The population standard deviation $\sigma$ is a parameter which is an unknown but fixed value. So what do you mean by "$\sigma$ depends on the unknown distribution"?

Answer (score 8):

To start off, there is a typo in statement 3: the population variance $\sigma^2$ is a parameter (unknown but fixed value), not a random variable, so it cannot be a pivot. It's the statistic $\widehat{\theta}$ which is not pivotal.

So the question boils down to comparing two statistics for the difference in means $\mu_2 - \mu_1$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\widehat{\theta} &= \overline{\mathbf{x}}_2  - \overline{\mathbf{x}}_1 \\
T &= \frac{\overline{\mathbf{x}}_2 - \overline{\mathbf{x}}_1}{\widehat{\sigma}\left(\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}\right)^{1/2}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Since $\mathbf{x}_1$ is iid $N(\mu_1,\sigma^2)$ and $\mathbf{x}_2$ is iid $N(\mu_2,\sigma^2)$, under the null hypothesis $H_0:\mu_1 = \mu_2$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\widehat{\theta} &\sim N\left(0,\sigma^2\left(\frac{1}{n_1} + \frac{1}{n_2}\right)\right) \\
T &\sim t_{n_1+n_2-2}
\end{aligned}
$$

$\widehat{\theta}$ is *not pivotal* because its distribution depends on an unknown parameter; $T$ is *pivotal* because its distribution depends only on the sample sizes, $n_1$ and $n_2$, which are known.

Here we are interested in comparing the two means, $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$, not in estimating the variance: $\sigma^2$ is a nuisance parameter. So it's convenient that the distribution of $T$ doesn't depend on the variance. There is no need to plug in an estimator $\widehat{\sigma}$ for $\sigma$ or use any of the other frequentist "devices" described in Section 2.1, in order to test the null hypothesis $\mu_1=\mu_2$. And our analysis (confidence intervals & p-values) will be equally valid for all values of $\sigma^2$.

Comment: A much better answer than the old, accepted one, IMO (+1).